# Custom deserialize from JSON navigating the response

Tags: c#, json, api, json-deserialization, system.text.json

I have a API that returns a JSON like the one below and I have to deserialize it in a C# object:

```
    {
      "found": true,
      "resultsData": [
        {
          "2023-05-13": [
            {
              "info1": "Test",
              "infoCode": 1,
              "infos": [
                {
                  "code": 2,
                  "extraInfo1": "test1",
                  "extraInfo2": "test2",
                  "extraInfo3": "test3",
                  "order": 1,
                  "risk": "",
                  "alarm": "alarm text"
                },
                {
                  "code": 3,
                  "extraInfo1": "test1",
                  "extraInfo2": "test2",
                  "extraInfo3": "test3",
                  "order": 1,
                  "risk": "",
                  "alarm": "alarm text"
                },
                {
                  "code": 4,
                  "extraInfo1": "test1",
                  "extraInfo2": "test2",
                  "extraInfo3": "test3",
                  "order": 1,
                  "risk": "",
                  "alarm": "alarm text"
                },
                {
                  "code": 5,
                  "extraInfo1": "test1",
                  "extraInfo2": "test2",
                  "extraInfo3": "test3",
                  "order": 1,
                  "risk": "",
                  "alarm": "alarm text"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "2023-05-14":  [
            {
              "info1": "Test",
              "infoCode": 2,
              "infos": [
                {
                  "code": 6,
                  "extraInfo1": "test1",
                  "extraInfo2": "test2",
                  "extraInfo3": "test3",
                  "order": 1,
                  "risk": "",
                  "alarm": "alarm text"
                },
                {
                  "code": 7,
                  "extraInfo1": "test1",
                  "extraInfo2": "test2",
                  "extraInfo3": "test3",
                  "order": 1,
                  "risk": "",
                  "alarm": "alarm text"
                },
                {
                  "code": 8,
                  "extraInfo1": "test1",
                  "extraInfo2": "test2",
                  "extraInfo3": "test3",
                  "order": 1,
                  "risk": "",
                  "alarm": "alarm text"
                },
                {
                  "code": 9,
                  "extraInfo1": "test1",
                  "extraInfo2": "test2",
                  "extraInfo3": "test3",
                  "order": 1,
                  "risk": "",
                  "alarm": "alarm text"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "message": ""
    }
```

If the "2023-05-13" is inserted inside the object like a property it could easy to deserialize that into a object but because this isn't deserializable into POCO object and it's not possible to change the API response I try to find a solution.
Following [this article from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/use-dom-utf8jsonreader-utf8jsonwriter?pivots=dotnet-7-0) I understand that I can deserialize manually using System.Text.Json and the JsonNode object and read property and value in a cicle loop.
I figure out how to obtain a Json node and object but I'm stucked for retrieve the "2023-05-13" value and the "2023-05-14" because they haven't a "name" like the others properties.
Any help with some code to figure out will be much more than appreciated

Comment: have you tried to deserialized it to `Map<string, object[]>` or something like that? Another way is to use custom json converter.

Comment: For `"resultsData"` use `public List<Dictionary<string, List<Info>>> resultsData { get; set; }`.  You don't need a converter or anything special beyond that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use  a Dictionary to get DateTime data

```
     Data data = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Data>(json);

public partial class Data
{
    [JsonPropertyName("found")]
    public bool Found { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("resultsData")]
    public List<Dictionary<string, List<ResultsData>>> ResultsData { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public partial class ResultsData
{
    [JsonPropertyName("info1")]
    public string Info1 { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("infoCode")]
    public long InfoCode { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("infos")]
    public List<Info> Infos { get; set; }
}

public partial class Info
{
    [JsonPropertyName("code")]
    public long Code { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("extraInfo1")]
    public string ExtraInfo1 { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("extraInfo2")]
    public string ExtraInfo2 { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("extraInfo3")]
    public string ExtraInfo3 { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("order")]
    public long Order { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("risk")]
    public string Risk { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("alarm")]
    public string Alarm { get; set; }
}
```